# What are the benefits of legendary skills?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I got pretty much all of my skills to level 100 on Skyrim, and now, I have the option to make them legendary.

I searched on the wiki and found that this will reset my level to the initial value i.e. 15.

I have also downloaded the skyrim community unlocker mod, which increases the level cap from 100.

So, my questions shortens to-
Is it beneficial to turn a skill legendary and get all your perk points back, or continue with leveling up with the help of the aforementioned mod I have installed?

I want to level up fast (The character level), so which one of the above would help achieve my goal with better efficiency? Also, are there any special items you get once you make all your skills legendary?

Comment: This is more a question of personal preference, which is not appropriate for a SE site. Personally, I woulnd't use the mod.

Comment: @YUNOWORK I am not asking for a personal opinion here, I am asking which of the two is actually beneficial in the long run. Many people have tried and tested both the methods, and may know which one is better in the long run.

Comment: @YUNOWORK So, do you actually know which method is better for my player level?

Comment: If you want faster levelling, then make a skill Legendary. Low level skills level pretty fast.

Comment: @JonK Yes, Low level skills level fast, but will my player level up faster with them? Or will it require 3-5 times the levels of the same skill to get levelled up. I don't actually know much about the character levelling system in Skyrim.

Comment: It's not the level of the skill that matters, each skill level-up is worth the same amount of 'XP' towards your character level - so a faster levelling skill will level your character faster.

Comment: @JonK But that XP must be fixed for particular levels. Thanks for this info (though I was already thinking about it). I guess levelling speed is pretty much unaffected by the way you go then? Is it? Also do you get anything when you turn your skill legendary?

Comment: You'd level more slowly if you have a mod that raises the skill level cap above 100, because the higher the level of the skill the more use it requires to gain a level. If for the sake of argument, getting from clevel 80 to 81 took 40 skill level-ups, you'd do that much faster if you were levelling a low level skill compared to a high level one. All you get from turning a skill legendary is a Skyrim icon beneath that skill to indicate that you've done it.

Comment: @JonK I am not worried about levelling the skill itself you see? Even if the skill stays on 100 for eternity, it does not matter, but what I am more interested in is in the character levelling. What I am understanding by your posts here is that - Character level has a designated XP, and you gain that every time you use a particular skill. So even if you reset to legendary, it will take the same amount of time as levelling up will still require the same XP.

Comment: No, skill level ups grant a fixed amount of 'XP', which is the same for all levels of all skills. Taking Smithing from 0 to 1 gives the same XP as taking Destruction from 99 to 100. Each character level requires a fixed amount of XP, and given that all skill-ups are worth the same amount of XP, a faster levelling skill (i.e. a low level one) will cause you to gain character levels faster, because you gain skill levels faster.

Comment: @JonK Thank you for bearing with me. I get what you are now!

Comment: I'll then just reset them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making skills legendary should be faster, unless the mod messes with the skill gain rates.  If it takes you longer to get from 100 to 101 than 15 to 16, then legendary is the way to go.

The fastest, by far, skill to make legendary is Illusion.  Getting to skill 90 is fairly fast with Muffle.

Casting Harmony in Whiterun will go from level 15 to about 55.  8 casts with the right bonuses (Well Rested, Mage Stone) will make it 100 again, and that will be about 2-3 levels.

As for the second question, legendary skills don't do anything other than letting you level it again, to gain more character levels.

Comment: Thank you. Bit I do not intend to use hacks to get levels faster. But still thank you.

Comment: None of what I described is hacks.  It is all legit and does not use any glitches.

Comment: I know, that the methods are legit, but I want to gain the skill by actually using the skill as I need them, not just randomly (That ruins the fun, doesn't it?). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how else you would "level up fast" but also am "using the skill as I need them".  I guess you are using the skill as you need them because you want to level up fast :)

Comment: If just standing in a town and casting Harmony seems like cheating, you can always switch to missions where it would make sense. For example, try stealing from bandit camps without killing anyone, just Muffle + Invisibility to get to good spots and Harmony to calm them down. If you want *fast* leveling, you are going to have to do some unusual things.

Comment: @JohnLaviolette That was what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The net benefit in the end is more magicka/health/stamina, because you'll have to choose either one when leveling up. Depending on your game-play style, this could increase the fun.

Spells you once learned, will always stay learned. When making a magicka depended skill legendary, you'll notice that spells will take more magicka to cast. If you are a higher level with, say, 600 magicka, you will be able to cast high end spells on a low skill level.

Answer (score 0):

Making skill legendary benefits you in way, that you can get levels and perk points again by leveling the same skill again.

The best one is Alteration because of this (sort of) exploit. If you enchant your gear to have lowered alteration cost by 20% (you need grand soul gem with grand soul) and enchant 5 pieces of armor, the mana cost of your alteration spells is gone.

After that is done, get telekinesis spell and pick up some random item like plate, hold it in the air with telekinesis and fast travel across map. Boom, your alteration level is instantly 100.

Make it legendary, rinse and repeat until satisfied.

Comment: Interesting!  I wonder what amount of level increase you'd get if you simply walked the full length of the map while levitating a plate, instead of fast travelling.